# How to use Identity Server 4 for authentication and authorization in a .NET microservices project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, microservices, identityserver4

I am building a microservice project that includes only the backend part and I am going to prepare apis for the front-end team. The project includes several systems, and our goal is to authenticate all systems through one project and control their access. We want to use identity server4 for the authentication project and our code is as follows:
Project configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AspNetIdentityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(defaultConnString,
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(assembly)));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AspNetIdentityDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    ;


builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddJwtBearerClientAuthentication()
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
        b.UseSqlServer(defaultConnString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(assembly));
    })
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
        b.UseSqlServer(defaultConnString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(assembly));
    })
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:37626";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

Primary data entered into the database:

```
 public class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResource
                {
                    Name = "role",
                    UserClaims = new List<string> { "role" }
                }
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new[] { 
                new ApiScope("CMS.API.Query"), new ApiScope("CMS.API.Command"),              
                new ApiScope("api") };
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
            new[]
            {
                new ApiResource("CMS.API")
                {
                    Scopes = new List<string> { "CMS.API.Query", "CMS.API.Command" },
                    ApiSecrets = new List<Secret> { new Secret("cmsapiscopessecretvirasystem".Sha256()) },
                    UserClaims = new List<string> { "role" }
                }
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new[]
            {                             
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "CMS",

                    
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("cmssecretvirasystemforemssystem".Sha256())
                    },

                    AllowedScopes = { "api" }
                }
            };
    }
```

Test controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public TestController(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        [HttpGet("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> login(string username, string password)
        {
           var discoveryEndpoint = await _httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:37626");

            if (discoveryEndpoint.IsError)
            {
             
                return BadRequest("خطا در دریافت متادیتا از Identity Server: " + discoveryEndpoint.Error);
            }

            
            var tokenResponse = await _httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
            {
                Address = discoveryEndpoint.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = "CMS",
                ClientSecret = "cmssecretvirasystemforemssystem",
                UserName = username,
                Password = password,
                Scope = "api"
            });

            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
               return BadRequest("خطا در دریافت توکن: " + tokenResponse.Error);
            }

            return Ok(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
        }
[HttpGet("GetUserInfo")]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserInfo()
        {
            var accessToken = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var userInfoResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:37626/connect/userinfo");

            if (userInfoResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var userInfoJson = await userInfoResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //var userInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserInfoResponse>(userInfoJson);
                // return userInfo;
                return Ok(userInfoJson);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle error response
                return BadRequest("Error");
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the login operation is performed correctly and the token is received. But to get the user information, there is a forbidden error

I even used the following code to get the user's information, but the user's username was not there:

```
[HttpGet("GetUserInfo")]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult<IActionResult> GetUserInfo()
        {
            var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", string.Empty);

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;

            var username = jwtToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value;

            return Ok(username);
        }
```